# Visibility of final fields not set in constructor

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, visibility, safe-publication

I've seen a class do something like this

```
class Foo {
private final Set<Bar> set = Collections.synchronizedSet(new HashSet<>));

     public void add(Bar b) {
          set.add(b);
     }   

}
```

However, the final set is not initialized in the constructor. Is it still visible to other threads?

Comment: Constructors implicitly include inline initializations like this.

Comment: I've never said "setting the visibility in the constructor" @Lothar

Comment: No? Look at the title of your question.

Comment: @LouisWasserman so are you implying that, this class and its set can be safely be published to other threads with full visibility?

Comment: The resulting bytecode is the same. This way you just avoid writing a constructor for simply initializing `set`.

Comment: "Visibility of final fields not set in constructor"
vs "setting the visibility in the constructor"

Two are different things. If you construct an object with final fields and set them inside the constructor, the JMM gives visibility to other threads when publishing that object, so as long as you don't let the this reference escape.

What I was asking is, would this have the same effect even though you didn't specifically do something like

public Foo(Set<Bar> set) {
    set = set;
}

Comment: @Kayaman sweet, so I guess you are implying yes to my question as well?

Comment: "Imply" sounds like there's a degree of uncertainty.

Comment: Well, I was looking for a yes to be sure. So may I ask if it's a yes?

Comment: Louis answered you, I answered you and Jim answered you with the duplicate explaining how it works.

Comment: okay, thank you all LouisWasserman, Jim Garrison and Kayaman